# CakePHP class not found using a custom class

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I just started using CakePHP 3. I'm trying to get up and running but doing the simplest of things is proving to be a headache.

I have a class, MySimpleClass, in `src/App/MySimpleClass.php`

```
<?php
    namespace MyApp\MyNamespace;

    class MySimpleClass {
        public function aSimpleFunction() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

And in my controller:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    use Cake\Controller\Controller;
    use MyApp\MyNamespace\MySimpleClass;

    class MyFirstController extends Controller {

        public function display() {
            $mySimpleClass = new MySimpleClass();
            echo $mySimpleClass->aSimpleFunction();
        }
    }
```

But this always gives me:
`Error in: ROOT/src/Controller/TestController.php, line 10 Class 'MyApp\MyNamespace\MySimpleClass' not found`

I use `bin/cake server` to run the HTTP server

I added `App::className('MyApp\MyNamespace\MySimpleClass');` to `bootstrap.php` to see if that'd make a difference but it doesn't.

I've run `composer dump-autoload` on several occasions.

I tried putting `MySimpleClass` into global namespace but it still gave me the error.

PHPStorm isn't giving me any syntax or naming errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your controllers in:

src/Controller

and use:

```
namespace App\Controller;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I finally found the solution...

I just had to add `src` to the classmap in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src"
    ],
    ...,
}
```

Edit:

Instead of abusing classmap, I just moved my class files to a directory outside of `src`

Comment: This is not so much a "solution" as a kludgy workaround. Putting implementation directly in the `src` folder is not good practice. Your directory structure should mirror your namespace structure, then you won't need this hack.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is in the file src/App/MySimpleClass.php, the namespace has to be `App\App`. The first `App` refers to the root namespace of every CakePHP 3.x application, the second `App` refers to the subdirectory within the `src` directory you put your class file into.

If the namespace of the class should be `App\MyNamespace`, your classfile has to be located in `src/MyNamespace`.

Also: according to the error message you quoted, your MyFirstController is in a file called TestController.php. Instead, it should be MyFirstController.php. I recommend giving https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions a read regarding this topic.